# i can get json and i stored in nsstring but i want to store that nsstring data in nsdictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7

i have the following code to get json and stored in nsstring but i want to store in nsdictionary..i tried some ways there is no solution for me ..help me thanks in advance

```
 [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *outfinal=[requestReply stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\""" withString:@""];

             NSLog(@"sender id array: %@", outfinal);




}] resume];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
NSDictionary * json  = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
                                           NSLog(@"%@",json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in following way, It definitely helps you. Don't forget to replace `URL`.

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"Replace your URL here"];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
 {
     NSMutableArray * jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
     if (error)
         NSLog(@"JSONObjectWithData error: %@", error);
     else
      {
     // Enter your code here to use Json Objects Store in JsonData(NSMutablearray)
     });
 }];
```

To retrieve values of Object stored in Array, use following code:

```
[[jsonData objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Key for retrieving value from Object"];
```

Comment: hi really thanks for your reply and am using iOS9 so when i use NSURLConnection it displays deprecated in iOS9 ..so is it display any error to me ?